# Linux awk string exec variable

Tags: linux, string, variables, awk, exec

i have a variable that when i echo it looks like this:

```
#echo $var
awk '{print  $7 " " $6 " " $8 " "}'
```

but if I try something like

```
#ls -lah | exec $var
awk: '{print
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `exec` you need to call `eval`:

```
ls -lah | eval $var
```

However 2 cautions here:

1. Parsing `ls` output should be avoided
2. Use of `eval` should be minimised

Answer (score 0):

Just put the awk script in a variable

```
var='{print  $7 " " $6 " " $8 " "}'
ls -lah | awk "$var"
```